# 2checkout how to use Direct Return

Tags: redirect, 2checkout

hi i'm using a demo account at 2checkout and i've added the approved url in the account details. Everythign works fine when using the Header Redirect because i receive data by $_REQUEST[] to insert these data into the database but don't know how to receive data using direct return without passing data through the url.

Comment: According to https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/api/, the API will return XML by default unless the Accept: header is passed in the call to define the content type. The API is capable of returning data in the following formats:
XML (application/xml) - default,
JSON (application/json),
HTML XOXO microformat (text/html)

Answer (score 0):

The Direct Return passback method works by posting the return parameters to your approved URL while it is being fetched by our server and displayed to the buyer. The URL will be masked to the buyer, appearing to still be on the 2Checkout.com domain. This method can be used with redirects as long as each page outputs content more than 255 characters to the browser. If Direct Return encounters a page that redirects without outputting content the process will fail and the buyer will be sent to our standard Order Processed page. If you are having problems with this return method please make sure that your page is outputting at least 255 characters before you redirect the buyer. We can help you with troubleshooting any issues that you encounter as well. Just contact techsupport@2co.com with your account number and we will be happy to help.